# How can i return data from a Collection with blog ID parameter from MongoDb using classmethod?

Tags: python, mongodb

I created a `Class(Blog)` with parameters`(author,title,description,ID)`,then after saving data to the MongoDB, i created a method `from_mongo` that will return data saved in the MongoDB from the blogs collection using `find_one` from Database Class with an ID value as argument. But as soon as the program runs it gives the error below:

```
return cls(author=blog_data['author'],
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Program :

```
    @classmethod
    def from_mongo(cls, id):
        blog_data = Database.find_one(Collection="blogs", query={'id': id})
        return cls(author=blog_data['author'],
                   title=blog_data['title'],
                   description=blog_data['description'],
                   id=blog_data['id'])

    @staticmethod
    def find_one(Collection, query):
        Database.DATABASE[Collection].find_one(query)

blog = Blog(author='Steve Fox',
            title='WCA',
            description='British Boxer')

blog.from_mongo('d8220db09ec1467696fa46b75aacd216')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your id is valid, you should be looking for `_id`.

`query={'_id': id})`